# getting BAD REQUEST in spring rest multipart image upload api

Tags: java, spring, rest, gridfs, rest-client

Here is a very dramatic situation for me, I don't what mistake supplying payload to rest client, because of which I am getting **"400: BAD REQUEST"** exception. Below is the code please help me solve it,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadQuestionImg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<FileMetadata> commonFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        FileMetadata fileInfo = null;
        HttpStatus statusCode = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                FileInfoService reqFile = createFileInfo(file, "");
                fileInfo = (FileMetadata) operations.store(file.getInputStream(), reqFile);
                statusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warn("Exception occured", e);
                statusCode = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Invalid request");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<FileMetadata>(fileInfo, statusCode);
    }
```

Here is the payload I am passing to the rest client,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`400: BAD REQUEST` error will arise when you try to request with the parameters that will not supported by the API.In your case your trying to POST a request ie , `Multi part file upload request`.the request should be in format of `multi part file request` else the server will throw `400: BAD REQUEST`

U can try http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically you can test `multi part file request` with this code.

Comment: I have already added a filter for multipart request:      **<filter>
  <display-name>multipartFilter</display-name>
  <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>**

Comment: **org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter** class to send muiltipart request...

Comment: If I am not wrong I have only one parameter to pass which i am passing "@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file". What else you think may be wrong.